# Error when upgrading to Magento to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

The upgrade process in composer works fine. After upgrading in composer en trying to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get the following error:

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data, Argument 2 passed to
> Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::resolveFullyQualifiedClassName()
> must be of the type string, null given, called in
> /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php
> on line 550

Anybody came across the same error? Any possible fix available?

**EDIT**:

To know which `extension/class` is responsible for the error, do the follow:

Open: `vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php` find the method `getMethodMapViaReflection()` and add the following to the first line:

```
echo $interfaceName . PHP_EOL;
```

Run `bin/magento setup:upgdrade` again. The last class just before the error is the suspect.

Credits to @JorgB for his answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of your custom modules is not Magento 2.4.4 compatible..

**How to fix?**
add PHPDOC block for all consumer class in your custom module.

**How to find all consumer class?**
you can set break point debugger in vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php or just wrap this method in try/catch block and print the class you need to fix.

**Or if you dont care to fix the modules now**
You can change line 550 of vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php to "return $type;" that way you can proceed with setup:upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, how do you know that? And how do I resolve which one it is?

Comment: Edited my question with more information

Answer (score 7):

find your not compatible custom modules in Magento 2.4.4.
add code in vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php line 143

```
    if($paramReflection->detectType() == NULL)
        {
            var_dump($paramReflection->getDeclaringClass());
            die();
        }
```

after you run setup:upgrade command, output showing like that

```
object(Laminas\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection)#7057 (2) {
  ["docBlock":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(36) "Magefan\Blog\Api\ManagementInterface"
}
```

in this output Magefan_Blog module is not compatible in Magento 2.4.4

Comment: Thanks it helps

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded my magento version from 2.3.5-p1 to version 2.4.5-p1 and I was facing the similar issue. I tried the solutions provided but it is not working anymore.

On the magento 2.4.5-p1 version, in order to find the class that is not compatible with the magento version, you have to do the following steps.

1. Open the file **vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceOutputProcessor.php**
2. In the **process** method, just after the line **$dataType = $this->methodsMapProcessor->getMethodReturnType($serviceClassName, $serviceMethodName);**
3. Add the below line of code, and it will give you the Class name and method name. **if($dataType === null || empty($dataType)){echo $serviceClassName.'<>'.$serviceMethodName . PHP_EOL;}**

Putting it here in case if someone need it.

Thanks